# getStringExtra() value is not getting set in URL

Tags: android

I have passed a value through putExtra from first screen and fetched by getStringExtra method to second screen. To confirm that I have received the value, I passed it as TextView on second screen and I was able to get it.

Now I am passing this value to url, but android studio is showing redline under it. During mouse rollover it shows following error.

> Cannot resolve symbol 'cropcategoryname'

The code is as follows.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

    TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cropCategoryName);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String cropcategoryname = i.getStringExtra("cropCategoryName");
    txtName.setText(cropcategoryname);
    } private String url = "http://dsy.impras.in/mup/cropname.php?cropcategory=" + cropcategoryname;
```

I believe it is a simple problem but I've been stuck on it for a while.

Comment: Post your intent sharing code.

Comment: The first screen code is as follows. lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
Intent cropcategoryIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CropnameActivity.class);
String cropCategoryName =((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.cropCategoryName)).getText().toString();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),cropCategoryName,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
cropcategoryIntent.putExtra("cropCategoryName", cropCategoryName);
startActivity(cropcategoryIntent);
}});

Comment: @KookyLibra When replying to requests for additional information, you should [edit] your question since you cannot format code in a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String cropcategoryname = i.getStringExtra("cropCategoryName");
```

This is a local variable in the onCreate() method.

```
private String url = "http://dsy.impras.in/mup/cropname.php?cropcategory=" + cropcategoryname;
```

This is an instance field in the activity class. The local variable in onCreate() does not exist when this code is executed.

I suggest that you learn about variable scope and the activity lifecycle. Since the value for `url` relies on a value that is only available in `onCreate()`, you **must** initialize `url` in that method, not inline with its field declaration:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

    TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cropCategoryName);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String cropcategoryname = i.getStringExtra("cropCategoryName");
    txtName.setText(cropcategoryname);
    url = "http://dsy.impras.in/mup/cropname.php?cropcategory=" + cropcategoryname;
}

private String url;
```

Comment: Application crashed. Logcat shows. FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.pj3, PID: 18832 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference at com.example.pj3.CropnameActivity$GetCropnames.onPostExecute(CropnameActivity.java:144) at com.example.pj3.CropnameActivity$GetCropnames.onPostExecute(CropnameActivity.java:56)

Comment: 144: lv.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: 56: private class GetCropnames extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CropnameActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                        pDialog.show();
        }

Comment: @KookyLibra You should post a new question with a minimal working example which causes the error. See [mcve] for tips on creating a code example which will help you get the answers you seek.

Comment: Now the answer by Code-Apprentice worked fine. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use this in your CropnameActivity before `onCreate`:

```
private static final String EXTRA_NAME = "EXTRA_NAME";
private String cropcategoryname;
private String url = "http://dsy.impras.in/mup/cropname.php?cropcategory=";

private static Intent createIntent(Context context, String cropCategoryName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CropnameActivity .class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, cropCategoryName);
    return intent;
}

public static void startActivity(Activity activity, String cropCategoryName) {
    activity.startActivity(createIntent(activity, cropCategoryName));
}
```

from your MainActivity do this:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 
     @Override 
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) { 
          String cropCategoryName =((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.cropCategoryName)).getTex‌​t().toString(); 
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),cropCategoryName,Toas‌​t.LENGTH_SHORT).show‌​();
          CropnameActivity.startActivity(MainActivity.this, cropCategoryName);
     });
```

then retrieve your `String` as such:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

    TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cropCategoryName);
    cropcategoryname = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_NAME);
    if(cropcategoryname != null) txtName.setText(cropcategoryname);
}
```

After that you can use the url String as such:

```
if(cropcategoryname != null) {
   String finalUrl = url + cropcategoryname;
}
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score -1):

Simply initialize the cropcategoryname string variable above the onCreate method.

```
    String cropcategoryname="";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

    TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cropCategoryName);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    cropcategoryname = i.getStringExtra("cropCategoryName");
    txtName.setText(cropcategoryname);
    } private String url = "http://dsy.impras.in/mup/cropname.php?cropcategory=" + cropcategoryname;
```

Comment: This also did not work. Application crashed with error. Logcat shows. FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.pj3, PID: 18832 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapte‌​r)' on a null object reference at com.example.pj3.CropnameActivity$GetCropnames.onPostExecute(‌​CropnameActivity.jav‌​a:144) at com.example.pj3.CropnameActivity$GetCropnames.onPostExecute(‌​CropnameActivity.jav‌​a:56)

Comment: This error that you are showing is not due to this, that is due to listview variable is null. Please post full code so that i can tell